# What is JuliaLang's equivalent to Python's sys.executable?

Tags: julia

I would like to retrieve the path of the currently running Julia interpreter from Julia. In Python, this can be achieved with `sys.executable`.

Comment: I guess that this path could be built by doing something like `string(JULIA_HOME, "/julia")`, but is there a more direct way to do so?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Base.julia_cmd()` is probably what you need. It returns the full command line that was used to invoke the current julia process, with the default options spelled out. `Base.julia_exename()` returns the name of the executable.

```
julia> Base.julia_cmd()
```

`/Users/aviks/dev/julia/julia5/usr/bin/julia -Cnative -J/usr/lib/julia/sys.dylib --compile=yes --depwarn=yes`

```
julia> Base.julia_exename()
"julia"
```

Comment: So to get the paths, I could simply do `split(string(Base.julia_cmd()))[1]`, I guess.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want the location of the julia executable, try one of these:

```
julia> julia_bin_exe = joinpath(Base.Sys.BINDIR,Base.julia_exename())
"/home/mkitti/src/julia/usr/bin/julia"

julia> Base.julia_cmd()
`/home/mkitti/src/julia/usr/bin/julia -Cnative -J/home/mkitti/src/julia/usr/lib/julia/sys.so -g1`

julia> typeof(Base.julia_cmd())
Cmd

julia> Base.julia_cmd()[1]
"/home/mkitti/src/julia/usr/bin/julia"

julia> julia_bin_exe == Base.julia_cmd()[1]
true
```